# Unknown provider: $rootscopeProvider <- $rootscope

Tags: javascript, web-applications, angularjs, jasmine

I'm trying to inject `$scope` into a jasmine test, but get the exception

```
Unknown provider: $rootscopeProvider <- $rootscope
```

My Spec file is this:

```js
describe("with data returned from NormDefinitions API", function () {
    const dummyData = [
        {"Id": 1, "Name": "Name 1", "Description": "Description 1"},
        {"Id": 2, "Name": "Name 2", "Description": "Description 1"}
    ];

    var $scope,
        mockService = {
            query: function () {
                return  dummyData;
            }
        };

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootscope) {
         $scope = $rootscope.$new();
    }));

    it("it can be instantiated", inject(function($controller) {
        var controller = $controller("NormDefinitionsController",
                {
                $scope: $scope,
                myService : mockService
            });

        expect(controller).not.toBeNull();
    }));
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `$rootScope` with capital `S`?

Comment: @MarkRajcok Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!  If you want to add it as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Why is this closed as too localized? It's a common typo with a popular framework. I stumbled on this question because of the exact same error, and the 3 upvotes suggest others have done the same.

Comment: Terrible choice to close this question.  This question and answer saved me tons of time.  I think this is what StackOverflow is all about.

Comment: Totally agree that this "too localized" decision was way off base. I banged my head against this problem for awhile before googling it and getting here. If you want to protect it from "me too!" comments, go ahead, but no way is this "too localized." It's an easy-to-make error with an easy solution.

Comment: I had the same issue with the typo $routeScope and the main benefit of this post was to make me double check for typos. Definitely not "too localized".

Comment: Apparently only BanksySan has typos.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Typo (happens to all of us):  `$rootScope` with a capital `S`.

Sometimes people forget to inject it.  Then you'd get this error:

```
ReferenceError: $rootScope is not defined
```

Comment: Those answers that make you feel like a total idiot. (sigh)

Comment: @Ganonside Those answers that make you feel not as alone when 46 other people upvoted it too :)